# How to use make/use a Doxygen filter in C++?

Tags: c++, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

The C++ code I have contains some home-made tags which need to be parsed in some specific way. Basically some part of the doc enclosed by some special  and  tags need to be saved as separate code which will be then executed on the fly to generate pictures.

I am at the very beginning of my tests. The filter itself should be written in C++.

I have made a stupid little sample just to see if the filter is invoked when I execute the Doxygen command. It looks like:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       printf("Hello\n");
    }
```

Then I defined in Doxyfile I defined:

```
INPUT_FILTER           = ./filter
```

But the "Hello" message doesn't show when I invoke the Doxygen command. What did I missed ?

Comment: use `strace` to understand how Doxygen runs your filter (or whether it is running at all). I suppose your filter should read `STDIN` at least...

Comment: strace is linux tool. I am on Mac.

Comment: then use whatever you have on Mac…

Comment: Anyway I do not need such tool. Clearly my filter is not called as the printout does not show. The question is, why the filter is not called ? ... I think this is a doxygen issue. I did not find the answer (yet) on the web.

Comment: probably you misunderstand the "filter" concept... if Doxygen use a filter it means that it feed it w/ input and grab the output. so, why do you expect it would "print" smth?

Comment: The doxygen manual says:  "The INPUT_FILTER tag can be used to specify a program that doxygen should invoke to filter for each input file. Doxygen will invoke the filter program by executing the command: <filter> <input-file>". So if this is true, my filter program should be executed. and I should se hundred of printout. But you are right I am surely missing something.

Comment: Ok, I am making progress. thanks for your help.

Comment: Read next (I took from the `INPUT_FILTER` description):
    Doxygen will then use the output that the filter program writes to standard output.

so you'll never see your "Hello", cuz Doxygen use output of your filter as a "preprocessed" source file... that is how filter concept works -- output of some program is a input for another/next one...

Comment: Actually i do see my "hello" in the html files Doxygen generated. I managed to completely messed up the doc. Thats good :-)

Comment: so, in brief, your filter should print a C++ (or whatever language) source code... maybe little bit modified.

Comment: Yes. My code has a special <begin_C> and <end_C>. I need to catch the code between these tags in a .C++ file which I will compile and execute. What I do not known is how to write the filter itself (I am using C++ also to write it). My first guess was to do a main program with argc and argv.. I am not sur was is passed there.. I continue to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The name of the file being analysed by Doxygen is passed as argv[1]; up to me to open it, read it, filter it the way I want.